# How long is the wire wrapped around a modern resistor?

Tags: resistors

So there is an equation for resistors that says:

[image]

Say rho is a small value such as a resistivity of copper which is 1.68 *10^-6. And we want the resistor to have a value of roughly 100kohms(for example). Say the area is small then the L value, the length of wire wrapped around the resistor is HUGE; literally miles of wire wrapped around a tiny resistor.

How is this possible? Inside a modern resistor today, how much wire is wrapped around to output desired resistances?

**Edit: Say you are in the 19th century with limited technology and you wanted to create this resistor using this equation (wrapping wires around an object to cause resistance), then the wires would have to be miles long right to achieve this value?**

Comment: If one uses a wire made of carbon, it would be shorter

Comment: 1cm^2 isn't small, 1cm^2 is a HUGE wire!!! (well, maybe people who work on the giant transmission lines would think it's small). Try 0.02mm^2 = 0.0002cm^2

Comment: @immibis my mistake. I thought it meant the total surface area of the wire wrapped around a cylinder. It makes more sense

Comment: you're assuming modern resistors are made this way.  Actually they are metallized plastic film

Comment: hehe. Great way to make a terrible inductor this way...

Comment: You use a wire made of some kind of high-resistivity material. Many cheap resistors are carbon-film resistors, which use graphite "wires". I believe wire-wound resistors use nichrome, a high-resistivity alloy of nickel and chromium. I don't know exactly what metal-film resistors are made of.

Comment: @Gonzik007 You can make non-inductive wire-wound resistors. You just need to have windings in both directions so they cancel each other out.

Comment: so lets say you want to make a resistor of this value(100kohms) long time ago when it was first invented with the equation then I would assume you would have wires 100's meters long huh?

Comment: @CuriousJ No, they would use wire that isn't huge. 1cm^2 is about the size of my pinky finger. You're using massive wire (that conducts a lot of electricity) and trying to make it not conduct very much electricity. Instead of pinky-sized wire try using hair-sized wire.

Comment: In ancient times (1950 - 1980), most resistors were carbon composition - a paste containing carbon grains compressed into a cylinder between two metal terminals.  The resistance could be adjusted by changing the composition of the paste.  No need for wires, except for the terminals for external connections.

Answer (score 7):

Typically wire-wound resistors use an alloy such [Manganin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manganin). It has a volume resistivity about 13 times higher than copper. There are other resistance wire alloys. Equally important, it has a low temperature coefficient and a reasonably low thermal EMF relative to copper. 100K is also a rather high value for a wirewound resistor- it would tend to be rather large, maybe 10-15mm long at a minimum, and close to the highest value for a standard part. They use a thin wire for high resistance, and much larger diameters for low resistances.

As an example, a proprietary NiCrAl resistance wire similar to Manganin is available in 0.015mm diameter, and has a resistance of about 7500\$\Omega\$/m so you'd need about 13m of it for a 100K resistor.

---

Chip resistors, of course, don't use wire, they have a very thin pattern of a material such as ruthenium oxide on a ceramic base, passivated with a layer of glass and trimmed by abrasive or laser. There are SMT metal foil resistors, some of which use clever tricks to achieve extreme accuracy and stability with temperature and time.

There are other materials such as carbon film (which is deposited onto a ceramic rod in an appropriate thickness for a given value, and then spiral cut to achieve a specific value, before being coated with lacquer and color bands).

Even a graphite pencil marking on a piece of ceramic can be used as a resistor. Generally resistors that are high value are typically film types. Up to 1T\$\Omega\$ resistors are not that difficult to make (way beyond what is typically useful). [Here](http://www.high-voltage-resistors.com/datasheets/high-voltage-chip-resistors-hvc.pdf) are some Ruthenium oxide resistors up to 1T "on request".

---

With regard to your edit, there was little need for precise stable resistor values in the 1800s. You could make a coarse resistor by mixing graphite with some kind of non-conductive binder. Early ones were made as a bare rod with wires wrapped around the ends, in fact it was possible to buy thermistors made that way as recently as 1985. When vacuum tubes became available, one application of high value resistors was the "[grid leak resistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid-leak_detector)". Below is a photo of one from 1926 (from the Wiki article)

[image]

According to [one source](https://www.antiqueradios.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=56380):

> All the old grid leaks were primitive and none of them were really reliable at their very best. The majority of the ones in a glass tube were made from a thin strip of cardboard soaked in India ink, and the resistance changed with the humidity.
>
> Some of the very early leaks used by experimenters were no more than a soft lead pencil mark that could be added to or erased for changing the resistance. I suppose you could call these the first variable grid leaks, and a few manufactured sets had this type under a small removable cap on the front panel.

Comment: Interesting but not modern

Comment: Too modern for the 19th century, by 26 or 27 years.

Answer (score 0):

Modern Carbon film resistor

Laser cut carbon film 
 [image]
 [image]

Photo is for 1Mohm
Stackpole Electronics Inc
Cost $0.02      HDM14JT100K     HDM14JT100K
Description     RES 100K OHM 1/4W 5% AXIAL

Carbon film resistor construction

In carbon film resistor, the desired resistance value can be achieved by either trimming the thickness of a carbon layer or by cutting the carbon metal in a helical manner along its length. This is generally done by using the lasers. The cutting of carbon metal is stopped once the desired resistance value is obtained.

The carbon film resistor is made by placing the carbon film or carbon layer on a ceramic substrate. The carbon film acts as the resistive material to the electric current. Hence, the carbon film blocks some amount of electric current. The ceramic substrate acts as the insulating material to the heat or electricity. Hence, the ceramic substrate does not allow heat through them. Therefore, these resistors can withstand at higher temperatures without any damage.

The carbon film resistor is made by placing the carbon film or carbon layer on a ceramic substrate.

Metallic end caps are fitted at both ends of the resistive material. The leads made of copper are joined at two ends of these metallic end caps. The resistive element of the carbon film resistor is coated with epoxy for protection.

The carbon film resistors are more preferred over carbon composition resistors because the **carbon film resistors produce less noise than the carbon composition resistors.**   (Metal film also produce less noise)

Carbon film resistor has high negative temperature coefficient of resistance

Resistance of carbon film resistor depends on the thickness of carbon film layer and width of helical carbon film cut

The resistance of the carbon film resistor is depends on the thickness of carbon film layer and the width of helical carbon film cut
Carbon film layer

**The resistance of the carbon film resistor is inversely proportional to the thickness of the carbon film layer.**

The carbon film resistors with very thin film layer allow only a small amount of electric current.

The resistance of the carbon film resistor is inversely proportional to the width of helical carbon film cut.

Advantages of carbon film resistor

```
Generates less noise than carbon composition resistor
Low tolerance
Low cost
Wide operating range
```

Disadvantages of carbon film resistor

```
High negative temperature co-efficient of resistance
```

[REF](http://www.physics-and-radio-electronics.com/electronic-devices-and-circuits/passive-components/resistors/carbonfilmresistor.html)